# Python : Modulus operator giving incorrect result

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, modulus

I am fairly new to Python and I am trying to implement the Hill Cipher as a small project. I think I have the logic figured out and have got the encryption part to work, however, in the decryption part, I am facing troubles. Especially with the modulus operator. In the decrypt function below, the second from last line is what is giving troubles.

```
import numpy as np
import fractions as fr

def decrypt(matrix, words):
    matrix=np.asmatrix(matrix)
    length = len(matrix)
    det_matrix=int(round((np.linalg.det(matrix))%26))
    mult_inv=(abs(det_matrix*26)/fr.gcd(det_matrix,26))/26
    matrix_inv=(((np.linalg.inv(matrix)*np.linalg.det(matrix))%26)*mult_inv)%26
    words = words.lower()
    arr = np.array([ord(i) - ord('a') for i in words], dtype=int)
    decrypt_matrix=(np.asmatrix(matrix_inv)*(np.asmatrix(arr).transpose()))%26
    return decrypt_matrix
```

My input to the decrypt function is:

```
>>> matrix
[[6, 24, 1], [13, 16, 10], [20, 17, 15]]
>>> words
'poh'
```

and after the calculation of `det_matrix`, `mult_inv` variable will have the value 25. So the line of code that calculates `matrix_inv` will have the below value, (which is absolutely correct):

```
>>> matrix_inv
array([[  8.,   5.,  10.],
  [ 21.,   8.,  21.],
  [ 21.,  12.,   8.]])
```

The array `arr` will have the value:

```
>>> arr
array([15, 14,  7])
```

The problem now is the next line of code, before performing the modulus the result of the expression

```
matrix_inv*(np.asmatrix(arr).transpose())
```

is:

```
matrix([[ 260.],
   [ 574.],
   [ 539.]])
```

And now, if I perform modulus 26 on the above matrix, I should get the output as

```
([[0.],[2.],[19.]])
```

However, below is what I get when I execute the expression

```
>>> (np.asmatrix(matrix_inv)*(np.asmatrix(arr).transpose()))%26
matrix([[ 26.],
     [  2.],
     [ 19.]])
```

I don't understand why the first element has been calculated incorrectly (260%26 is 0 and not 26)! However, the remaining two elements have been computed correctly!

Any help on this is much appreciated!!

**P.S : I have tried running the code on versions 2.7.11 and 3.6.1. Does not work on either.**

Comment: the only thing i tried so far is to check if `(matrix @ matrix_inv)%26 = 1`. it is not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that `det` is a `numpy.float64`. what you are getting could be something like:

```
round(259.6 % 26) # -> round(25.600000000000023) -> 26.0
```

this works:

```
round(259.6) % 26  # 0
```

in your decrypted result you have:

```
dec = decrypt(matrix, words)
dec[0,0]      # 25.999999999989768
dec[0,0] % 26 # 25.999999999989768
```

it will just be displayed as `26.`

---

as i was interested in having a modular inverse for 3x3 matrices, i wrote some code... maybe this is useful for you...

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product, cycle


def gcd_xy(a, b):
    '''
    extended euclidean algo: return (g, x, y): g = gcd(a, b); a*x + b*y = d.
    '''
    q, r = divmod(a, b)
    x, y, x1, y1 = 0, 1, 1, 0
    while r != 0:
        x1, y1, x, y = x, y, x1 - q*x, y1 - q*y
        b, (q, r) = r, divmod(b, r)
    return b, x, y


def mod_inv(e, n):
    '''
    return d == 1/e mod n or raise ValueError if e and n are not co-prime.
    '''
    g, d, _ = gcd_xy(e, n)
    if g != 1:
        msg = '{} has no inverse mod {}'.format(e, n)
        raise ValueError(msg)
    d %= n
    return d


def mod_inv_matrix(matrix, n):
    '''
    modular inverse of 3x3 matrix 
    '''

    inv = np.zeros((3, 3), dtype=int)

    det = round(np.linalg.det(matrix))
    det_inv = mod_inv(det, n)

    matrixT = matrix.T
    for (i, j), sign in zip(product(range(3), repeat=2), cycle((1, -1))):
        m = np.delete(np.delete(matrixT, i, axis=0), j, axis=1)
        inv[i, j] = sign * det_inv * round(np.linalg.det(m)) % n
    return inv


def hill_decrypt(matrix, words):

    matrix_inv = mod_inv_matrix(matrix, n=26)

    words = words.lower()
    arr = np.array([ord(i) - ord('a') for i in words], dtype=int)

    plain = (matrix_inv @ arr) % 26

    return plain

matrix = np.array([[6, 24, 1], [13, 16, 10], [20, 17, 15]], dtype=int)
words = 'poh'
dec = hill_decrypt(matrix, words)
print(dec)
```

for the modular inverse you could also just use the [`gmpy` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2)

```
import gmpy
gmpy.invert(7, 26)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll take some time to digest this. But, it's really strange that the same logic (the one I have written) works when I provide a 4x4 input but does not work with this 3x3 input!

Comment: don't you think that is just by chance? (and yes: my answer does not provide a solution for general `n*n` matrices).

Comment: I guess so. I think I'll spend some more time investigating (and understanding better) this weird behaviour of the program.

Answer (score 0):

works OK in Python 3.5, Spyder `Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

```
matrix_inv = np.array([[  8.,   5.,  10.],
   [ 21.,   8.,  21.],
   [ 21.,  12.,   8.]])

matrix_inv
Out[182]: 
array([[  8.,   5.,  10.],
       [ 21.,   8.,  21.],
       [ 21.,  12.,   8.]])

arr = np.array([15, 14,  7])

arr
Out[184]: array([15, 14,  7])

(np.asmatrix(matrix_inv)*(np.asmatrix(arr).transpose()))%26
Out[185]: 
matrix([[  0.],
        [  2.],
        [ 19.]])
print(np.__version__)
1.11.1
```

Comment: I am using
    `2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]`
I'll upgrade the version and try again. Thanks!

Comment: Does not work on 3.6.1 also.
    `3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]`

Comment: sounds like possible bug - have to interest someone knowing a lot more than me to tease out the problem